# Storing MySQL Field Datetime in PHP Variable and Adding 1 Hour To It

Tags: php, mysql

Using MySQLi and PHP I have a Query Like below and I need to store the  `orderdate` field from MySQL `newOrder` table (with format of `Datetime` like `2014-06-15 22:12:00`) into a PHP variable like `$orderTime` and then add 1 Hour to the Time.

```
<?PHP
include 'conconfig.php';
$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
$query = "select * from newOrder WHERE orderdate < NOW() ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

 if ($result = $con->query($query)) 
{
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {}
    else
    {
        $resultStr = 'Nothing found';
    }}
}
$con->close();
```

is it possible something like inside the while loop?

```
$orderTime = $row['orderdate'];
$orderTime = $orderTime +1hour;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily done with [**date()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [**strtotime()**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$orderTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($row['orderdate'] . '+ 1 hour'));
```

---

**Update to answer question in comment:**

To check if difference between `$ordertime` and current time is greater than 2 hours:

```
if (time() - strtotime($orderTime) > 7200) {
    echo 'Difference is greater than 2 hours';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark just can you also let me know how I can check if the difference time of the $orderTime and Now() is greater than 2 hours or not?

Comment: I just noticed on issue here

Comment: it seems the code adding 1 hour after each page load! can we stop this?

Comment: @MonaCoder Sorry, I don't know why that would be happening. As long as the DB is not being updated, then each time the script runs it should be grabbing the DB value and adding 1 hour to that time. Maybe you are somehow carrying over the value of `$orderTime` and adding an hour to that, on top of the hour already added? Not sure, sorry. It may be an altogether unrelated problem - maybe you could write out the code you think is the problem and post a new question. Will try to help if I can :)